# The largest possible area of the rectangle on a parabola

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

A rectangle has its base on the x-axis and its upper two vertices on the parabola $y = 49 - x^2.$  What is the largest possible area (in square units) of the rectangle?

I do not know how to write the area formula though, I am guessing that it is $x \times y = x \times (49 - x^2)$ am I correct? and then I have to differentiate and equate the differentiation to zero after that.

My question is my formula for the area correct? or it needs to be multiplied by 2? if so why?

Comment: Draw a figure... all will become clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always draw a picture.

If you assume the rectangle has horizontal sidelength $2x$, then this is the picture:
[image: rectangle]

The area of the rectangle is $f(x) = 2x \cdot (49-x^2)$. This function is maximal when $f^\prime(x) = 98 - 6x^2= 0$, i.e. when $x=\frac{7}{\sqrt{3}}$.

Thus the maximal area is $$f\left ( \frac 7 {\sqrt{3}}\right) = \frac{14}{\sqrt{3}}\left( 49-\frac {49}3\right)=\frac{1372}{3\sqrt 3}$$

Comment: So, why can not I just say that the base is $x$ and not $2x$?

Comment: It depends on your convention. In my case, i choose to call $x$ the abscissa of the right corner. You can call it $x/2$ if you prefer, but then in the parabola formula, you need to adjust for it, i.e. $49-(x/2)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that in order to be a rectangle, its upper vertices must be $(x, 49-x²)$ and $(-x,49-x²)$, because a point $A$ and a point $B$ in a parabola will only form a horizontal straight line if $B$ is the vertical reflection of $A$. Its lower vertices will have to be $(x,0)$ and $(-x, 0)$, because they are the perpendicular projection of the upper vertices on the $x$-axis. So, the length of the basis is $x-(-x)=2x$, therefore you must multiply by two. With that in mind, just apply the same algorithm you would before: multiply $2x$ and $y$, differentiate it, and then equal it to 0.

Comment: Amazing! +1, that is exactly what I am asking

Answer (score 1):

$A = 2 x (49 - x^2)$

Find $x$ s.t. $\frac{d A}{d x} = 0$.  (Answer:  $x = 7/\sqrt{3}$)...

Can you finish from there?

[image]

Comment: So, why can not I just say that the base is $x$ and not $2x$?

Comment: Because the problem requires you to find the AREA.  (If the problem wanted one corner of the rectangle to be at the origin, it would have stated that.). Note that optimizing $A$ or $A/2$ gives you the same solution for the right edge of the rectangle, of course.